# foreman, DHCP smart proxy, network set-up

Tags: networking, provisioning, foreman

How would I go about setting foreman up so it hands out a lease to any machine I connect to one of its interfaces using a private IP in the 192.168-range during provisioning, but to supply the client with it's actual IP (either public, or private in a 10.10 net) for operation via ansible?

I don't want to (it's also against our policy) to hand out DHCP on the production server network.

My foreman install is on ubuntu 14.04, running in a VM with two network interfaces; eth0 is static on the server network, eth1 is 192.168.0.1 in a 192.168.0.0/24 ... running in a VM.